# Javascript: Merging / renaming similar objects in array by same key/value

Tags: javascript, node.js, functional-programming, lodash

With this sample object array:

```
[{
   "Element ID": "299",
   "Element Name": "Manager",
   "Scale ID": "IM",
   "Data Value": "3.5"
},
{
   "Element ID": "299",
   "Element Name": "Manager",
   "Scale ID": "LV",
   "Data Value": "3"
},
{
   "Element ID": "300",
   "Element Name": "FinTech",
   "Scale ID": "IM",
   "Data Value": "1.75"
},
{
   "Element ID": "300",
   "Element Name": "FinTech",
   "Scale ID": "LV",
   "Data Value": "1.38"`
}]
```

I wrote this code to merge duplicate objects by `Element ID` and rename some elements:

```
let p = {};
const output = input
  .map(s => {
    if (_.isEmpty(p)) {
      p = s;
      return {};
    }
    if (p['Element ID'] !== s['Element ID']) return {};
    const result = {
      name: s['Element Name'],
      id: s['Element ID'],
      importance:
        p['Scale ID'] === 'IM'
          ? p['Data Value']
          : s['Scale ID'] === 'IM'
            ? s['Data Value']
            : null,
      level:
        p['Scale ID'] === 'LV'
          ? p['Data Value']
          : s['Scale ID'] === 'LV'
            ? s['Data Value']
            : null,
    };
    p = {};
    return result;
  })
  .filter(n => Object.keys(n).length);
```

So it now outputs the desired format of:

```
[{
   "name": "Manager",
   "id": "299",
   "importance": "3.5",
   "level": "3"
},
{
   "name": "FinTech",
   "id": "300",
   "importance": "1.75",
   "level": "1.38"
}]
```

It's a complicated method and fails if the input object array doesn't have exactly two similar objects next to each other in the array. Is there a better method via `lodash`, `.reduce()` or similar I'm not considering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
const resultObject = originalArray.reduce((result, element) => {
  const id = element["Element ID"];
  const resultElement = result[id] || { 
    id,
    name: element["Element Name"],
  };

  switch (element["Scale ID"]) {
    case "LV":
      resultElement.level = element["Data Value"] || null;
      break;
    case "IM":
      resultElement.importance = element["Data Value"] || null;
      break;
  }


  return {
    ...result,
    [id]: resultElement,
  }
}, {});

const resultArray = Object.keys(resultObject).reduce((result, key) => ([
  ...result,
  {
    "id": key,
    ...resultObject[key],
  }
]), []);
```

`originalArray` is your data.

You can improve this by moving the keys into constants. Just try to make your code readable. The algorithm is not that complicated. Refrain from using libraries for simple tasks like this. Javascript already is very powerful.